# Something prevented updates from being installed, but the app's name is blank

Tags: macos, software-update, error

Has anyone seen this?

So basically I'm wondering if this has happened to anyone else, or if my computer might be infected with malware or something.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using something like Malwarebytes to scan for malware?

Comment: Nope, I'll try that.

Comment: I got this too back in December, never figured out what it was.